# Eclipse doesn't open file for reading

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, file

I tried to put the **.txt** file in the same folder. It doesn't fix the problem. In the code I check if the file is open. In the console I get "error". Why is this happening?? How do I solve this problem?

Here is part of my code:

```
ifstream input("text.txt");
if (input){
    while(input){
        getline(input, line);
    }
    cout << line << endl;
    cout << "done";
} else {
    cout << "error";
}
```

Comment: Maybe the file is in the wrong folder or has a different name. If you don't know what the correct folder is create a new file (using a unique filename like 20190117.txt)  in your program. And use you OS file explorer to see were it puts the file.

Comment: In the same folder as what? Whatever assumption you are making about the correct folder, it's wrong (assuming no other errors like wrong file name etc). I'm pretty sure there's an eclipse setting that will let you set the current working directory when you start your application.

Comment: AFAIR, Eclipse starts programs by default in main project directory, so you may need to adjust the path to the the file or Eclipse settings.

Comment: Sidenote: The current positioning of `cout << line << endl;` seems a bit odd.

Comment: In the launch configuration in the tab _Arguments_ you can choose the working directory (which is by default the project directory).